# Is there a Python code to extract relative information of the dupliacte ID's and get a merged information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, data-extraction

| Serial Number | Age | Characteristics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20 | Tall |
| 1002 | 23 | Blue |
| 1001 | 20 | Black |
| 1002 | 23 | Short |
| 1003 | 19 | Green |

Desired output:

| Serial Number | Age | Characteristics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 20 | Tall,Black |
| 1002 | 23 | Short,Blue |
| 1003 | 19 | Green |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first use `groupby` then in `agg` use ','.join like this

```
df.groupby("Serial Number").agg({"Age": "last", "Characteristics": ','.join})
```